# Why do I need to move the accuracy variable to the GPU after importing the model to the GPU in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

here are my relevant code for this question:

```
 if args.resume:
        if os.path.isfile(args.resume):
            print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(args.resume))
            if args.gpu is None:
                checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)
            else:
                # Map model to be loaded to specified single gpu.
                loc = 'cuda:{}'.format(args.gpu)
                checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume, map_location=loc)
            args.start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
            best_acc1 = checkpoint['best_acc1']
            if args.gpu is not None:
                # best_acc1 may be from a checkpoint from a different GPU
                best_acc1 = best_acc1.to(args.gpu)

            model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

            optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])

            print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                  .format(args.resume, checkpoint['epoch']))
        else:
            print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(args.resume))
```

Details of my question are i can not figure out why do I need to move the best accuracy variable to the appointed GPU after importing the full checkpoint information to the appointed GPU in PyTorch

```
 if args.gpu is None:
                checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume)
```

and

```
if args.gpu is not None:
                # best_acc1 may be from a checkpoint from a different GPU
                best_acc1 = best_acc1.to(args.gpu)
```